# Crons in cron.d won't run on Ubuntu running inside Docker Container

Tags: ubuntu, docker, amazon-ec2, cron, ubuntu-16.04

I have written a very small program consisting mainly of Scrapy scrapers. I have it packaged in a docker container and need the scrapers to be called by cron.

My docker-compose file is:

```
version: '2'
services:
  admin-panel:
    env_file: ./Admin-Panel/.env
    build: ./Admin-Panel/
    volumes:
      - ./Admin-Panel/app:/code/app
      - ./Admin-Panel/flaskadmin.py:/code/flaskadmin.py
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
  scraper:
    env_file: ./Admin-Panel/.env
    build: ./Scraper/
    volumes:
      - ./Scraper/spiders:/spiders
```

My Scraper Dockerfile is:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
ENV TERM xterm

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y python3-pip python3.5-dev build-essential  
RUN apt-get install -y libssl-dev nano cron libpq-dev libffi-dev curl

ADD ./requirements /requirements
ADD crontab /etc/cron.d/scrapers

RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip
RUN pip3 install -r /requirements/base.txt

RUN touch /var/log/cron.log

CMD cron && tail -f /var/log/cron.log
```

My crontab is (with a trailing new line):

```
* * * * * root /usr/local/bin/scrapy runspider /spiders/myspider.py
* * * * * root /bin/date >> /tmp/cron_output
```

This works perfectly well when running locally on my Mac running Sierra but when I put in on Amazon EC2 instance running the Amazon Linux AMI the crons do not get called. I used Filezilla to transfer the files from my Mac to my Amazon EC2 instance.

AWS EC2:

> Docker version 1.12.6, build 7392c3b/1.12.6

My MacBook:

> Docker version 17.03.0-ce, build 60ccb22

If I add the line

```
* * * * * root /bin/date >> /tmp/cron_output
```

using crontab -e nothing happens either. The file cron.log is empty.

UPDATE:

I installed rsyslog and then started it:

```
service rsyslog start
```

Now in /var/log/syslog

> Mar 25 21:49:01 4406b0e05b9f CRON[464]: Cannot make/remove an entry for the specified session

Comment: A docker container doesn't run a full suite of services.  It is highly likely that crond is simply not running in your container, unless you have explicitly configured it to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a solution thanks to https://github.com/sameersbn/docker-gitlab/issues/173

I commented out the following line in /etc/pam.d/cron

```
session    required     pam_loginuid.so
```

Just need to work out how to do this automatically on docker-compose up.

Comment: That works indeed, found out how to do it with docker?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding permissions to the Dockerfile, e.g.,

`RUN chmod 0744 /spiders/myspider.py /etc/cron.d/scrapercron`

and change the location of the crontab

`ADD scrapercron /etc/cron.d`

Then in your crontab...

`HOME=/spiders
* * * * * root /spiders/myspider.py >> /tmp/cron_output 2>&1`

And to test, try outputting to that tmp file

`CMD cron && tail -f /tmp/cron_output`